# Peculiar "maximum recursion depth exceeded" when coding farey sequence

Tags: python, c++, recursion, math

I coded a program that given x, outputs a completly reduced fraction of x. I used this method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence The problem is that when i input "0.1111111111" I get an error:

```
    farey(l, m, a2, b2, x, iterations+1)
  [Previous line repeated 988 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

But, when I input "0.111111111111111111111111111111" for example the code works good and outputs 1/9.

```
def farey(a1, b1, a2, b2, x, iterations):
    l = a1 + a2
    m = b1 + b2
    f = l/m

    if iterations == 100000:
        print(str(l) + "/" + str(m))
        return 0

    if x > f:
        farey(l, m, a2, b2, x, iterations+1)
    elif x < f:
        farey(a1, b1, l, m, x, iterations+1)
    else:
        print(str(l) + "/" + str(m))
        return 0


farey(0, 1, 1, 1, 0.1111111111, 0)
```

I ported the code to C++ and the code behaves exactly the same as in Python, so the problem must by in my program's logic. I tried sys.setrecursionlimit(100000) in Python but nothing changed. Here is the C++ code

```
#include <iostream>
typedef unsigned long long ull;
using namespace std;


int farey(ull a1, ull b1, ull a2, ull b2, double x, unsigned int iterations) {
    double f = (double)(a1 + a2) / (b1 + b2);

    if (iterations == 100000){
        cout << a1 + a2 << "/" << b1 + b2;
        return 0;
    }

    if (x > f) {
        farey(a1+a2, b1+b2, a2, b2, x, iterations + 1);
    }
    else if (x < f) {
        farey(a1, b1, a1+a2, b1+b2, x, iterations + 1);
    } 
    else{
        cout << a1 + a2 << "/" << b1 + b2;
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    farey(0, 1, 1, 1, 0.1111111111, 0);
}
```

Comment: If you use a debugger to step through both functions line-by-line, it should be obvious where the behavior starts deviating between the two.

Comment: A double holds about 17 significant digits.  So, when you type `0.1111111111` with 10 significant digits, that's actually `0.11111111110000000`, which is not at all equal to 1/9.  This algorithm simply does not work with floating point approximations.

Comment: Your code only stops when `x == f` and that will probably never happen

Comment: When I see `typedef unsigned long long ull;`, I vote down. There is `uint64_t`.

Comment: You also have undefined behavior in your C++ code because only the else branch returns a value.  All other paths out of your function do not and not returning a value in a value returning function is UB.

Comment: Okay I found the issue. The only difference between your code was your value of `x`. In your Python code it has 10 decimal places and in the C++ code it has 23 decimal places. Well, if you just change it to 23 decimal places in Python, then the recursion limit is not reached. So, it's not clear why you thought that having that difference would still end up with both programs being identical. I don't know why you wrote different values and expected the same output.

Comment: @NathanOliver how so? The `else` guarantees something will be returned eventually. If the `else` is never reached, that's not UB, since nothing is being returned; that's a logic error, in that case, not undefined behavior, I'd think.

Comment: @RandomDavis Lets say we call the function for the first time and `(x < f) == true`.  That means it's going to call `farey(a1, b1, a1+a2, b1+b2, x, iterations + 1)`.  Now lets say in that call `(x == f) == true`.  You return `0`, but you are returning `0` to the first call of `farey`, not the calling code.  In that first call you'll exit the if block, skip the else block because you were in the if block, and then you fall of the end of the function without returning anything.

Comment: @NathanOliver oh, of course. makes perfect sense.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The different x input in python and c++ is an oversight I made when copying the code, but the behaviour is still the same in both languages. I've since changed the code to include a marigin of error when comparing (x == f). It makes the code work in some cases (like the one in question), but overall it's obviously not the solution as it gives false results in many cases. https://pastebin.com/kLxu5rBr